# Use tcolorbox in beamer template for alert block in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, beamerarticle

I want to have boxes in the `article` version of my `beamer` slides, i.e. with `beamerarticle.sty`. I tried to use `tcolorbox` in the beamer templates.
While this work well for the `block` environment, I get a LaTeX error for `alertblock`.

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \endtcolorbox ->\tcb@insert@after@part

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[]
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
   \end{tcolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[]
}
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
  
\begin{block}{Foo}         % Works
    Bar
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{Alert!} % Error
    Foo
\end{alertblock}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `block alerted begin` two times instead of one with `end`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    title={\insertblocktitle}
  ]
} 
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted end}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}
  
\begin{block}{Foo}         % Works
    Bar
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{Alert!} % Error
    Foo
\end{alertblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]